# How to query this in Mysql? I need to get the numbers

Tags: mysql

my table consist of 2 columns

| first_id | second_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |

What is the query to get the following values?

| first_id | second_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |

so I just want the 1,2 and 2,3 pairs excluded from the result?

Comment: Please post the current Query you are trying and what is the current result

Comment: you need to explain the logic otherwise 'select * from myTable where second_id > 3;' will work with your sample

Comment: Did you find the answer below helpful? Do you want any additional help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example and the query:

```
create table test (first_id int, second_id int);
insert into test values (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3);
```

Query:

```
select *
from test where not
( 
  (first_id = 1 and second_id = 2)
  or
  (first_id = 2 and second_id = 3)
);
```

Result:

> ```
> first_id | second_id
> -------: | --------:
>        1 |         3
>        1 |         4
> ```

Example

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=708aae05c61a533a9278dc1e4b2e89ac

Comment: So, if I need another pair of numbers to exclude, I will just add an or statement with the 2 numbers, like "or (first_id=x and second_id =y)"?

Comment: Yes, @Ian, you got it. That’s what you’d do. If this answer is sufficient, you can put closure to your question by marking an answer as accepted by clicking on a check mark by an answer.